# How to unit test this code with private implementation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I know there are questions are are similar to this, but none seem to satisfy the correct way to address the following code snippet in regards to unit testing

```
public class InMemoryQueue : ICloudQueue
{
    private Queue<object> _inMemoryCollection = new Queue<object>();
    private readonly ServiceBusQueueSettings _settings;

    public InMemoryQueue(ServiceBusQueueSettings settings = null)
    {
        _settings = settings;

        if (_settings == null) _settings = new ServiceBusQueueSettings();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReceieveAsync<T>(int batchCount)
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
        {
            _inMemoryCollection.Dequeue();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public async Task AddToAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        items.ToList().ForEach(x=>_inMemoryCollection.Enqueue(x));
    }
}
```

OK, I want to unit this this implementation of ICloudQueue to ensure that items that are added to via AddToAsync are held in memory, and any call to RecieveAsync is pulled from memory.

However - the complication is that the data is held in _inMemoryCollection which is a private variable.
If the _inMemoryCollection queue WASNT private, one of the tests might look like this :

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Adding_To_Queue_Results_In_Message_Added_To_List()
    {
        //arrange
        var listToAdd = new List<object>() { new object() };
        var inMemoryQueue = new InMemoryQueue();

        //act
        await inMemoryQueue.AddToAsync(listToAdd);

        //assert
        Assert.IsTrue(inMemoryQueue._inMemoryCollection.Count == 1);
    }
```

I guess I could change the _inMemoryCollection to be internal, then use the [InternalsVisibleTo] attribute to expose it to the unit tests. Although I'm reluctant as it means changing the implementation just to satisfy unit tests.

Is this my only option?

Comment: Expose an `int QueueSize` or `bool IsEmpty` property or something like that?

Comment: Surely all you really care about is that an item added in `AddToAsync` will be dequeued by following call to `ReceiveAsync`? In that case you don't need to worry about the implementation and can test through the public interface.

Comment: Well I don't think we need a unit test to observe that `ReceieveAsync<T>()` as currently implemented will always either return an empty list or throw an `InvalidOperationException`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real implementation of the queue within `InMemoryQueue` can be provided by the dependency injection (by constructor for example), which will allow you to test it:

```
public class InMemoryQueue : ICloudQueue
{
    private IQueue<object> _queue;
    private readonly ServiceBusQueueSettings _settings;

    public InMemoryQueue(IQueue<object> queue, ServiceBusQueueSettings settings = null)
    {
        _queue = queue;
        _settings = settings;

        if (_settings == null) _settings = new ServiceBusQueueSettings();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReceieveAsync<T>(int batchCount)
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
        {
            _queue.Dequeue();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public async Task AddToAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        items.ToList().ForEach(x => _queue.Enqueue(x));
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` do not implement any `IQueue<T>` interface, so you must to introduce it:

```
public interface IQueue<T>
{
    void Enqueue(T item);
    T Dequeue();
    int Count { get; }
}
```

So to test `InMemoryQueue` with `Queue<T>`, a wrapper must be written:

```
public class QueueWrapper<T> : IQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> queue; 
    public QueueWrapper()
    {
        queue = new Queue<T>();
    }
    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        return queue.Dequeue();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return queue.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

And eventually test looks:

```
public async void TestMethod()
{
    //arrange
    var listToAdd = new List<object>() { new object() };
    var queue = new QueueWrapper<object>();
    var inMemoryQueue = new InMemoryQueue(queue);

    //act
    await inMemoryQueue.AddToAsync(listToAdd);

    //assert
    Assert.IsTrue(queue.Count == 1);
}
```

Comment: But this now has forced the `InMemoryQueue` to expose an implementation detail, namely that it is using a `Queue<T>` internally. This is not a good design. Imagine if Microsoft took this approach with the design of `List<T>` and forced you to pass in a `T[]` to the `List<T>` constructor...

Comment: @Honza Brestan, I agree it is quite idealist point of view but I think it is better to have it here as a reference than not. It depends also if `InMemoryQueue` will grow with its functionality etc.

Comment: @Matthew Watson I must disagree, I see `InMemoryQueue` as a higher level abstraction service, not a framework collection like `List<T>`. And it can use in-memory MSMQ if one decide to do that. Dependency injection let's you test functionality of `InMemoryQueue` independent of internal implementation - for test, ideally `IQueue<object> queue` should be injected with some mocked object (from `Moq` for example).

Comment: Are you saying that you think that the implementation's use of a `Queue<T>` is NOT an implementation detail? I'm pretty sure that it is... You could, for example, have used a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead.

Comment: @Matthew Watson of course it is, that's why I said that using mocked object would be ideal. I think the matter is how we treat `InMemoryQueue`. If like low-level collection like `List<T>`, then you are right. If like high-level service, then I should be more correct.

Comment: Well I'm just going to have to disagree from a usability point of view. As a user of the class, I don't want to have to both know about AND have to construct and pass in a `Queue` for it to use internally - furthermore, if I do so it means I can queue and dequeue to and from the `Queue` from outside the class, by accessing the object that I was forced to create and pass in to the constructor. Is it safe to do that, do you think? Do you think the queue is safely encapsulated if other code has a reference to it?

Comment: @Matthew Watson in general, you are right. But by going into that direction, all dependency injection can be seen as unwelcome from usability point of view because it somehow exposes internal implementation. Because I see `InMemoryQueue` as a higher level service than you, I should provide users a factory to create it with default implementation or wrap it (as a derived class for example). But I have a feeling our discussion is becoming too academic and arises from our different look at `InMemoryQueue` class.

Comment: I know this is the most contested answer, but I feel that it is the only one that addressed the problem at hand as it will result in a dependency free unit test. (ie : only testing 1 method, not both)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can check if items which you added to queue was queued by receiving them back (actually this is expected behavior of your queue):

```
[Test]
public void Can_Receive_Added_Items()
{
    //arrange        
    var listToAdd = new List<object> { new object() };
    var inMemoryQueue = new InMemoryQueue();

    //act
    inMemoryQueue.AddToAsync(listToAdd).Wait();

    //assert
    var queuedItems = inMemoryQueue.ReceieveAsync(listToAdd.Count).Result;
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(listToAdd, queuedItems);
}
```

BTW Currently you are not adding items to `result` list when dequeueing them, so your test will fail.

Comment: +1, focuses on the interface/contract behaviour, not checking private implementation details.

Comment: I was of the understanding that unit tests are meant to be isolated. In this example, the AddToAsync() may be working fine, but there is a dependency on RecieveAsync working, that could end up skewing the reliability of the test?

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley Sometimes you just can't avoid this kind of compromise. The main thing is, does testing it like this increase the chance of a false pass? In this case, I think it very unlikely.

Comment: @Honza Brestan, I believe method that is testing both `AddToAsync` and `ReceieveAsync` is not real unit test.

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley it is because there is a hidden dependency on the queue. OOP purists would argue that you need to use DI, expose the queue dependency and test agains a fake queue (then you can set expectation for `AddToAsync` and `ReceiveAsync` and verify them separately), but that is overdesign IMO in this case. Line has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: +1 Internal implementation should not be considered. The behaviour of the class as a whole is what matters.

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley agree, it's better to have ability for testing add and remove functionality separately. But if your queue has single responsibility which tells `added items should be received` and there is no options to see items count in the middle or some events like `item addded` (your clients don't need that behavior), then you should do exactly what clients of your queue would do - add items and receive them back.

Comment: OK, well what if RecieveAsync<T> didn't exist and AddAsync<T> was the only method in there that required testing? I kind of regret putting RecieveAsync in there as I feel that it has allowed an answer that avoids the real issue at hand - how we go about testing code where the element needed to be asserted is hidden behind a private as part of the design.

Comment: @PatrickMcCurley if there was no `ReceiveAsync` method, then what behavior your clients would expect from this queue? If you'll answer this question, I'll tell you what should be tested in that case :)

Comment: In this case the client would expect AddAsync<T> to add the given object to an in-memory collection

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to change the approach of your testing.

You will have to write your test from the process perspective.

First perform an Add, and then perform a Receive. You should have to assert the element you have received is the same that you have added.

If you want to ensure there was just one element added, perform a Receive again an ensure you get an empty list.